# Camel - ActiveMQ reacting to empty queue

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a ActiveMQ queue that is being filled by messages from two diffrent processes. The first one supplies the queue with actual messages, the other one adds the "keepAlive" type of message to the queue every few seconds. Messages from that queue are consumed by a single process with camel-netty endpoint.

The "keepAlive" message has to be sent only when there are no other messages being sent in a given time frame. That's why I want to modify the "keepAlive" process to fill the queue only when there are no other messages in that queue which meet certain criteria (e.g. one of the header values equals something)

Is that achievable using only XML route and process definition (without custom code implementation) ?

Comment: So you want to monitor the queue and if no messages arrive, you want to send keep-alive messages to it. Can you explain what this keep-alive thing is for? who is kept alive with it? My first thought is that the first process should notice that it does not send anything for a certain time and therefore send keep-alive messages instead.

Comment: Yes this could also be the case, sadly I don't know how i could react to a one process being 'idle' and not producing any messages.